# Why does placing a menu block on a page stop the page from being cached for anonymous users?

Tags: caching

If I show a menu block on a page, that page will never be cached for anonymous users. Is that expected behaviour or is it caused by something else on our site? If it is caused by something else, please could you suggest how I can track down what is causing it?

---

Our site is running D9.4.5.

I was watching the cache_page table, and noticed that every time I visited a page as an anonymous user, that page's record in cache_page was updated.

I tried removing blocks one by one, and found that if I removed all the menu blocks then the page is cached. If I add back any menu block, caching stops.

The menu block shows a simple list of links that are the same on every page, and never change, so I didn't expect them to prevent the page from being cached.

So, is this expected behaviour?

I expect it's more likely I'm doing something in some other piece of code that is causing this, but I'm not sure how to track it down.

---

Update #1

I added a call to logger() in Core's invalidateTags() to see if anything was resetting cache tags, but I don't see anything logged when I refresh a page.

I've also enabled debug headers, and set up some example pages:

https://gwulo.com/media/28127 - standard page with several menu blocks enabled. If I view as an anonymous user and refresh the page, the page doesn't cache. x-drupal-cache: is always MISS

https://gwulo.com/media/33370 - all menu blocks hidden. This page will cache, and I'll get x-drupal-cache: HIT

https://gwulo.com/media/33371 - just one, simple menu block enabled in the footer. Page won't cache.

Comparing x-drupal-cache-tags: for the last two pages above, the non-cacheable 33371 has an extra cache tag 'config:system.menu.footer-left-'

---

Update #2

Though the call to logger() in cache.php's invalidateTags() didn't show anything related to the above cache tag, the tag did appear at the bottom of Drupal's Redis report:

MOST INVALIDATED CACHE TAGS
config:system.menu.footer-left-: 1263

That report was run a short time after restarting the Redis service, so it looks as though the tag is being invalidated on every page view.

A grep for 'invalidate' in modules/contrib showed a call in the Menu Token module that looks suspicious, and there's an issue for that module reporting a similar problem: https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token/issues/3224197

There is a duplicate issue https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token/issues/3171015 that has a patch to solve the problem, but as I can live without the Menu Token module I've just uninstalled it.

The Redis report shows no more invalidations of the config:system.menu... cache tags, and pages now cache successfully for anonymous users.

Comment: Check any customization module installed for Menu, which might be resetting cache tags.

Comment: How have you determined the page is not cached?

Comment: Drupal makes it possible to debug caching: https://www.drupal.org/node/3162480

Comment: Thank you for your replies.

Comment: @Sharique I added a call to logger() in Core's invalidateTags() to see if anything was resetting cache tags, but I don't see anything logged.

Comment: @Jaypan First I noticed the page's record in cache_page was being updated on each visit. Then I enabled the x-drupal-cache: header and with the Menu Blocks displayed I only get MISS, but if I remove them I get HIT.

Comment: @cilefen Thanks for the tip. If I've still got this problem when we upgrade to 9.5 I'll certainly try that.

Comment: Fixed now. Short version: listen to @Sharique! Turned out to be the Menu Token module causing it.

Longer explanation in the edited notes above.

Thanks again for the help.